# List packages by last run time?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I am mostly interested in Ubuntu and apt but also curious about other package managers.

Is there a way of seeing the last time a package was executed (or lib accessed etc) so I can target under utilised packages for removal to free up space?

Comment: How would you determine from the count what packages to delete? If a backup program runs once a week or less, and you delete it, someone's not going to be happy.

Comment: @Kusalananda I’m thinking more like if a package hasn’t been run for months, if ever. Besides, I’m mostly asking about a family desktop PC for which I am the admin and would have a very good idea if a package was being used by one of my kin. What triggered it was noticing Blender was installed and I don’t know why. Possibly I used it to do something a long time ago but I don’t recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a tool which can help you do that on Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu: `popularity-contest`. If you install it, even without participating, you can get a list of the last access and change times of all installed packages by running `popularity-contest`:

```
/usr/sbin/popularity-contest
```

(it doesn’t need to run as root).

An additional tool in the same package, `popcon-largest-unused`, will quickly determine the largest unused packages, based on `popularity-contest`’s output:

```
/usr/sbin/popularity-contest | sudo tee /var/log/popularity-contest
/usr/sbin/popcon-largest-unused
```

(You don’t need to manually run `popularity-contest` here if you choose to participate by uploading your reports, since that will update the `/var/log/popularity-contest` every day.)

Comment: This works well. Thanks.