# Check which packages were used after boot

Tags: linux, boot, package-management

Is it possible to list all packages, which were used by Linux from boot to current time? I'm making one app system and I think about removing all unnecesary packages to run this app. If it is important - I use systemd and apt.

Comment: A better way: Read `man dpkg apt-get apt` to learn how to find dependencies, and even graph them.

Comment: It is not bad idea, I was woried about apps, which I wrote myself, but I found `ldd` command

Comment: Would it be fair to say then that the real question is how to determine the packages that are required to run a given (unpackaged) application?

Comment: Hmm, if it is equal to set of packages that are required to start linux properly and run app I think that yes. Main question is how to run app in possible short ammount of time but probably this would be too general and I wouldn't get answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by looking for files which have been accessed since the system booted:

```
find / -xdev -anewer /proc/version -type f
```

You’ll need to add mountpoints as necessary; *e.g.* if `/usr` is a separate file system, run `find / /usr -xdev ...`.

Post-processing that will allow you to determine the packages involved; since you’re using `apt`, we’ll ask `dpkg`:

```
find / -xdev -anewer /proc/version -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

You can get a subset of this information using `popularity-contest`; see [List packages by last run time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585742/86440) for details.

I highly recommend producing a minimal package for your application, so that its dependencies can be identified; this will help avoid issues with upgrades. Packaging doesn’t have to be complicated; see [Vincent Bernat’s pragmatic Debian packaging guide](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2019-pragmatic-debian-packaging) to get started. (One major benefit is that the packaging tools will determine library requirements for you and determine the corresponding dependencies.)